# Client and Server PCs are not connecting within a LAN

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, lan

I`m trying to connect a Java Client with a Server in the same LAN, client and server are in two different PCs.

Here goes my Client Code,

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    String ip = "192.168.0.103";
    int port = 9999;

    Socket s = new Socket(ip,port);

    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String msgin = " ";
    String msgout = " ";

    while(!msgin.equals("end")){
      msgout = br.readLine();
      dout.writeUTF(msgout);
      msgin = din.readUTF();
      System.out.println("Mr.Client : "+msgin);
    }

  }
}
```

The Server PC has a IP of 192.168.0.103 .

Here is the Server code,

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    System.out.println("Server started ... ... ");
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9999);

    System.out.println("Waiting for client request ... ... ");
    Socket s = ss.accept();

    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String msgin = " ";
    String msgout = " ";

    while(!msgin.equals("end")){
      msgin = din.readUTF();
      System.out.println("Mr.Server : "+msgin);
      msgout = br.readLine();
      dout.writeUTF(msgout);
      dout.flush();
    }

  }
}
```

Whenever I`m running these codes, the Server shows it is waiting for the Client but after running Client, the Client becomes frozen for unlimited time, stays stuck, no output.

To be mentioned, the Client is running on a Ubuntu machine and Server is on a Windows one.

When I ran the Client and Server in Windows PC using localhost, it worked without any issue.

Some clue would mean great help. Thank you.

Comment: Are your ports open and free on windows

Comment: Yeah, I have checked nothing is running through those. That is why it seems really weird.

Comment: Are both machines on the same subnet. Check ipconfig and ifconfig for your adapter up addreses

Comment: The Ubuntu is 192.168.0.102 and the Windows 192.168.0.103